# How to set isotope's elements position to relative

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope to dynamically load data as it comes in.
I am initialising isotope on the container as follows:

```
var $container = $('#content-main-list');
var imgLoad = imagesLoaded($container);

imgLoad.on('always', function() {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'article',
        layoutMode: 'straightDown',
        position: 'relative',
        isFitWidth: false,
        resizable : false,
    });
});
```

This results in the following html being constructed:

```
<div id="content-main-list" class="isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 15670px;"> 
    <div class="blog">
        <article class="format-standard isotope-item" style="margin-right: 10px; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        . . .
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="blog">
        . . . 
    <div>
    <div class="blog">
        . . . 
    <div>
</div>
```

I would like the elements (articles) to have a relative position instead of an absolute one. Is there a way to easily do this? Isotope seems to overwrite all my attempts at ensuring articles stay relative no absolute.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try `!important`?

Comment: !important Sorry could you clarrify on that ? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: That's a CSS keyword to mark a property as high importance, making it very hard to override. Instead of `position : relative;`, write `position : relative!important;`

Comment: Thats done the trick. Thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `!important`. That's a CSS keyword to mark a property as high importance, making it very hard to override. Instead of `position : relative;`, write `position : relative!important;`